# Lambda Edge Origin Request 502

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am getting in the invocation of lambda edge in origin request for Cloudfront, this error, I am trying to change the metatags of a Single Page Application done to React:

*Validation error: The Lambda function returned an invalid entry in the headers object, the header must have a value field, header: cache-control has one or more entries which doesn't have a value field.*

And this is my lambda edge function

```
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const zlib = require('zlib');
let originalUri;
const downloadContent = (url, callback) => {
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    let response;
    let body = '';

    if (res.headers['content-encoding'] === 'gzip') {
      response = res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
    } else {
      response = res;
    }

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
      callback(true, body, res.headers);
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => callback(false, e));
};

const fetchMetaData = (url, callback) => {
  downloadContent(url, (isOk, result, headers) => {
    if (!isOk) {
      console.log('Error fetching meta data:', result);

      callback(false);
    } else {
      const metaData = JSON.parse(result);
      let metaTags = '';
              console.log('metaData whate:', metaData);



      if (metaData) {

        if (metaData.title) {
          metaTags += '<title>' + metaData.title + '</title>';
          metaTags += '<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"' + metaData.title + '\" />';
        }

        if (metaData.description) {
          metaTags += '<meta name=\"description\" content=\"' + metaData.description + '\" />';
          metaTags += '<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"' + metaData.description + '\" />';
        }

        if (metaData.images) {
          for (let i = 0; i < metaData.images.length; i++) {
            const image = metaData.images[i];

            metaTags += '<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"' + image + '\" />';
          }
        }
      }

      metaTags += '<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"' + originalUri + '" />';
      metaTags += '<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"website\" />';

      callback(true, metaTags, headers);
    }
  });
};

const fetchIndexHtmlAndCreateCloudFrontResponse = (url, metaTags, metaHeaders, callback) => {
  downloadContent(url, (isOk, result, headers) => {

    if (!isOk) {    
      callback(false);
    } else {
      var finalBody = result.replace(/(<title>title<\/title>)/gi, metaTags);
      const responseHeaders = {
        'content-type': [{key:'Content-Type', value: 'text/html'}],
        'content-encoding' : [{key:'Content-Encoding', value: 'gzip'}],
        'accept-ranges': [{key:'Accept-Ranges', value: 'bytes'}]
      };
      let eTag = '';
      if (metaHeaders) {
        const metaEtag = metaHeaders['etag'];
        if (metaEtag) {
          eTag = metaEtag.replace(/"/g, '');
        }
      }
      if (headers) {
        const lastModified = headers['last-modified'];
        const cacheControl = headers['cache-control'];
        const contentETag = headers['etag'];
        if (lastModified) {
          responseHeaders['last-modified'] = [{key:'Last-Modified', value: lastModified}]
        }
        if (lastModified) {
          responseHeaders['cache-control'] = [{key:'Cache-Control', value: cacheControl}]
        }
        if (contentETag) {
          eTag += contentETag.replace(/"/g, '');;
        }
      }

      if (eTag !== '') {
        responseHeaders['etag'] = [{key:'ETag', value: eTag}]              
      }
      const newResponse = {
        status: '200',
        statusDescription: 'OK',
        headers: responseHeaders,
        body: finalBody,
      };

      callback(true, newResponse);
    }
  });
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { request, response, config } = event.Records[0].cf;

  originalUri = request.uri;
  const parsedPath = path.parse(originalUri);

  if (parsedPath.ext === '' && parsedPath.dir === '/collections') {
    console.log('parsedPath:', parsedPath.base);
    request.uri = '/index.html';

    let metaUrl = 'https://a2mfja.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testenv/metatags';
    fetchMetaData(metaUrl, (isOk, metaTags, metaHeaders) => {
      if (!isOk) {
        return callback(null, request); // Return same request so CloudFront can process as usual.
      } else {
        const contentUrl = 'https://d3lyhnumbmrole.cloudfront.net/index.html';
        fetchIndexHtmlAndCreateCloudFrontResponse(contentUrl, metaTags, metaHeaders, (isOk, newResponse) => {
          if (!isOk) {
            return callback(null, request);
          } else {
            //newResponse.headers = request.headers;
            return callback(null, newResponse);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    return callback(null, request);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error was here, cacheControl was undefined in the headers:

```
 if (lastModified) {
      responseHeaders['cache-control'] = [{key:'Cache-Control', value: cacheControl}]
    }
```